# Is there any visual process mapper/debugger for Erlang?

Tags: debugging, graph, erlang, visualization, remote-debugging

So I would love to see where is a bottelneck in my processes communication interaction. Is there any plugin/vm extension/ software that could provide records of Erlang processes interactions?

Comment: `observer:start()` might help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a cool visualization tool demonstrated in a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHoWfeNuAN8) by Kresten Krab Thorup.

Maybe it can help you "see" bottlenecks.

The code is available [on github](https://github.com/krestenkrab/erlubi).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other tools, the `dbg` suite contains on-line tracing tools, in particular with time stamps and message passing tracing. This can be used to build up a view of where time is spent. Also, consider adding `folsom` to your application and measure the time different parts are taking.

Answer (score 0):

There is such thing called et_[viewer](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/et_viewer.html) and the excellent [article](http://jlouisramblings.blogspot.ru/2011/10/using-event-tracer-tool-set-in-erlang.html) how to use it.
General idea is to put probes in certain places in the code, and then build sequence diagram from it.